# Why static-sized array type cannot be a container type?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have an alias to a static-sized array, using it is easy and straightforward:

```
using triplet_t = std::uint8_t[3];

//           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- easier than std::uint8_t(&triplet)[3]
void f(const triplet_t &triplet) { /* whatever */ }

triplet_t t{}; // As good as std::uint8_t t[3]{};

t[0] = '0';
t[1] = '1';
t[2] = '2';
for (auto &v : t) std::cout << v << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

// So far so good...
triplet_t t3[3]{};
for (auto &r : t3)
    for(auto &v : r)
        v = 42;
```

I can even use the alias in containers:

```
std::vector<triplet_t> vt;
```

Or so I used to think, because as soon as you use `vt` it fails:

```
vt.push_back({});
```

> GCC 8.0.0 201711
>
> ```
> error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
> { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> error: request for member '~unsigned char [3]' in '* __p', which is of non-class type 'unsigned char [3]'
> destroy(_Up* __p) { __p->~_Up(); }
>                     ~~~~~~^~~
> ```

The issue seems to be that after unrolling all the template trickery a placement-new is called forwarding all the parameters provided parenthesized, and obviously this is not the way to initialize a static-sized array.

Also, somehow the container thinks of `triplet_t` as an object and hence is asking for a destructor, failing again to compile. The issue is obviously the same without the alias:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t[3]> vt;
vt.push_back({});          // Boom!
vt.push_back({255, 0, 0}); // Ouch!
```

But no problem using a `struct` with the same memory layout:

```
struct rgb { std::uint8_t r, g, b; };
std::vector<rgb> vt;
vt.push_back({});          // Nice!
vt.push_back({255, 0, 0}); // Cool!
```

I wonder why this happens, is there a way to use static-sized arrays as contained type in containers?

Comment: _"is there a way to use static-sized arrays as contained type in containers?"_ Should work using `std::array`.

Comment: C-arrays are not copyable.

Comment: Do you get the same result with `using triplet_t = std::array<std::uint8_t,3>`?

Comment: A struct wrapper may help.  `struct chocolate { std::uint8_t[3] nougat; }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 your comment just makes me think about why people ask questions about C/C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), `push_back` requires the value type to be either `CopyInsertable` or `MoveInsertable`. Let's see the [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable):

> The type T is **CopyInsertable** into the container **X** whose value_type is identical to **T** if **T** is MoveInsertable into X, and, given [...] the following expression is well-formed:
>
> ```
> std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
> ```

So in the case of a C-array, one has, for the standard allocator, an expression [like](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct)

```
::new((void *)p) int[3](std::forward<int[3]>(v))
```

where v is of the array type. This is ill-formed, according to the [specification of new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> - If type is an array type, an array of objects is initialized.
>
>   - If initializer is absent, each element is default-initialized
>   - If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is value-initialized.
>   - If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the array is aggregate-initialized.

There is no syntax for array types allowing for non-empty parantheses.

The argumentation goes quite similarily with the `MoveInsertable` category.
All in all, the proposed solution would be the (already mentioned) use of `std::array` which is itself not of array type and therefore can be initialized properly by the syntax taken by standard allocators' `construct` function.

One final note: the strict aliasing rules only allow for conversions of any type with `unsigned char`, `signed char` or `char`. While almost certain that `std::uint8_t` is just an alias typedef on one of those in your implementation, there is no guarantee in the standard for this.

Answer (score 5):

Reading [`std::vector` documentaion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), you can find that `T` must meet the requirements of [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and CopyConstructible.

This means (simplifying): with `v` and `t` two instances of type `T`, the expression `t = v` must be legal. Clearly, if `T` is a native array, this is not the case (you cannot assign a C-array to another), and certain functions of `std::vector<T>` would be ill-formed.

A solution would be to define `triplet_t` as:

```
using triplet_t = std::array<std::uint8_t, 3>;

void f(const triplet_t &triplet) { /* whatever */ }

triplet_t t{};

t[0] = '0';
t[1] = '1';
t[2] = '2';
for (auto &v : t) std::cout << v << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

// So far so good...
triplet_t t3[3]{};
for (auto &r : t3)
    for(auto &v : r)
        v = 42;

std::vector<triplet_t> vt;

vt.push_back({});
```

Comment: Actually, push_back doesn't require the type to be `CopyAssignable`, but `CopyInsertable` or `MoveInsertable`.

Comment: @Jodocus Once UB is invoked, all is the same in the grand scheme of nasal demons ;) But I agree your answer is better. I'll upvote it;)

Comment: It's not actually UB. If you read the very link you posted more carefully, since C++11, `vector` does not require the type to be `CopyAssignable`. The strict rules got relaxed, meaning the type requirements are determined by the operations actually performed, not the container.

Comment: @Jodocus I thought it was cppreference simplifying things, but you're right. According to [`[vector]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector), those are requirements and the implementation must provide a diagnostic. This is not UB ^^.